# Where do I find my AccountSharedKey in Windows Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Its been awhile since I had used Azure and I forgot where to find my account shared key and I cannot find it on the portal. Where should I be looking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://windows.azure.com/Cloud/Provisioning/Default.aspx

... then select project name.

Comment: Thanks, I found it. I was clicking the service project and expecting it to be there. I needed to click the Storage project and there it was.