# Azure AccountName and AccountSharedKey problem

Tags: azure

I'm obviously not smart enough to figure it out on my own.  Even after reading [the very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621161/where-do-i-find-my-accountsharedkey-in-windows-azure), I'm still far from solving this problem.  I'm sure that once again stackoverflow community will save me.

I'm trying to update ServiceConfiguration.cscfg file and I'm having problem to get the right account name.  It's also possible that I'm using the wrong AcountSharedKey.

```
<ConfigurationSettings>
   <Setting name="DiagnosticsConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<ACCOUNT_NAME>;AccountKey=<ACCOUNT_KEY>"/>
</ConfigurationSettings>
```

Let assume that I have the following endpoint:
**http://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net**

And my primary access key:
**"some_very_long_key"**

I tried to put these values in DiagnosticsConnectionString section.  Somethihg like this:

```
<ConfigurationSettings>
   <Setting name="DiagnosticsConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=http://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net;AccountKey=some_very_long_key"/>
</ConfigurationSettings>
```

I'm oviously doing something wrong and I'm sure that you know what it is.

While waiting for someone to help me I also try this without any success:

```
<ConfigurationSettings>
   <Setting name="DiagnosticsConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=mystorage;AccountKey=some_very_long_key"/>
</ConfigurationSettings>
```

**UPDATE:**
  When I try to publish, I see a message box with the following error:

> *There was a problem sending the command to the program.*

Comment: I'm not an Azure pro, I've never seen an endpoint used for the account name, so I'm thinking you're use of "mystorage" is more appropriate, assuming that is the proper name.  Can you be more specific about what you mean by "publish"?  You're trying to publish the project locally, or do you mean you're uploading to the public Azure service?

Comment: I publish by clicking right button on the Azure project in VS and select 'Publish'.

Comment: VS 2008 or VS 2010 Beta 2 or other?  Has it ever worked on your computer?  You must have the Azure tools installed?

Comment: I tried it on both VS2008 and VS2010 Beta 2.  I always get the same error: "There was a problem sending the command to the program." .  I never was able to make it work on my Windows 7 machine.  However, it creates a package and I can successfully deploy it using Windows Azure Web portal.

Comment: I had a similiar problem once when I was running vs as an administrator ... is your user an administrator or do you run vs.net as an administrator? When I had problems when I ran vs.net as an administrator but I was logged in as a non admin.  When I actually logged in as an administrator and tried it everything worked fine.

Comment: @Jason.  I'm logged in as an administrator and I ran VS as an administrator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have deployed some sample Azure application successfully. You should not touch the DiagnosticsConnectionString property. You need to define one more connection property, e.g. "DataConnectionString" and provide the account details and use that in application. Based on your details, the sample configuration would be as below:

```
    <ConfigurationSettings>
  <Setting name="DiagnosticsConnectionString" value="UseDevelopmentStorage=true" />
  <Setting name="DataConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=mystorage;AccountKey=some_very_long_key" />
</ConfigurationSettings>
```